# Undefined PHP property in class

Tags: php, oop, pdo

For the sake of the thread I have only 2 PHP classes, one for the Database and one for Users in my database.

When running the executing the code in my Users class a PHP notice is displayed on my browser stating..

> Notice: Undefined property: Database::$escape in
>   /my/directory/user.class.php on line x

In my Users class I have the following code:

```
$Database = new Database();
$submitData = array_map($Database->escape, $submitData);
$result = $Database->query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email_address = " . $Database->quote($formData['email_address']));
```

In my Database class I have the following:

```
class Database { 
    private $db = array();
    private $connection;
    public $result;      

    public function escape($data) {
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $data);
    }   
...
```

Comment: use __set() and __get() magic methods to avoid this error !!

Comment: ah escape() is a method and u r trying to access as member variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inproper callback, correct callback:

```
$submitData = array_map(array($Database, "escape"), $submitData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give your Database instance another name, i think, when you want to use

```
$Database->escape
```

, php refers to

```
Database::$escape
```

, which is a static variable of the class Database, and such is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have array_map of $Database-> escape  which searches for that property and throws the error. You should have a callable function's name like "escape" or some other function.